Using both APOC and GDS libraries in NEO4J
I am new to Neo4j, I apologize for asking this simple question. As a test, I created a graph database and applied several GDS algorithms such as degree centrality, community, etc. Then, I decided to work with APOC library. Since I run neo4j-community-5.19 with console, I installed the APOC with the following procedure:

copying apoc-5.19.0-core from lab to the plugin directory

creating an apoc.conf file (inside the conf folder) with the following content:
apoc.import.file.enabled=true

modifying the neo4j.conf as:
dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=apoc.coll.,apoc.load.,gds.,apoc.
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc., gds.
server.config.strict_validation.enabled=false

I change the permission of neo4j.conf to read only access of one user

I run the following commands:
neo4j.bat console --expand-commands
neo4j.bat restart


Now, there are two issues:
A) trying call gds.version retruns
2.6.6
CALL apoc.import.csv works, but call apoc.meta.data() gives me the following error:
apoc.meta.data is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict procedures you can trust with access to database internals.
B) my previous script (which only uses GDS algorithms) gives following error:
message: gds.degree.write is unavailable because it is sandboxed and has dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict procedures you can trust with access to database internals
I apprecaite if anyone can help.

It seems that the (above) mentioned errors do not occur, if neo4j.conf modified as:
dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,gds.*,apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*, gds.*, jwt.security.*
server.config.strict_validation.enabled=true
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false

But in this case apoc.conf will not be recognized.
